# Numero de variables. Error

Tags: php

No encuentro el error, a ver si alguien me dice que estoy haciendo mal. Me agrega el registro pero me da un error antes.

*Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /resultados_insertar_registros.php on line 32.*

```
$seccion = $_GET['SECCIÓN'];
$nombreart = $_GET['NOMBREARTĪCULO'];
$fechas = $_GET['FECHA'];
$pais = $_GET['PAÍSDEORIGEN'];
$precio = $_GET['PRECIO'];


require("conexion.php");

$sql="INSERT INTO ARTÍCULOS (SECCIÓN,NOMBREARTÍCULO,FECHA,PAÍSDEORIGEN,PRECIO) VALUES ('$seccion', '$nombreart', '$fechas','$pais', '$precio')";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);
$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "sssss", $seccion, $nombreart, $fechas, $pais, $precio ); 

$ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);

if($ok == false) {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";
} else {
    echo "Registro agregado <br><br>";
}

mysqli_stmt_close ($resultado);
```

Comment: Al parecer tienes dos cuentas, te recomiento que entres a este enlace para que puedas unirlas [ https://stackoverflow.com/contact ]

Answer (score 0):

en esta parte

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ARTÍCULOS (SECCIÓN,NOMBREARTÍCULO,FECHA,PAÍSDEORIGEN,PRECIO) VALUES ('$seccion', '$nombreart', '$fechas','$pais', '$precio')";
```

no va así?

```
$sql='INSERT INTO ARTÍCULOS (SECCIÓN,NOMBREARTÍCULO,FECHA,PAÍSDEORIGEN,PRECIO) VALUES (?,?, ?,?,?)';
```

Tu le estas pasando directamente las variables y luego las estas agregando otra ves

```
$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "sssss", $seccion, $nombreart, $fechas, $pais, $precio );
```

Comment: Hola!! exactamente era eso!!! muchisimas gracias!!! Me esta pasando que ya no veo los errores. Creo que necesito vacaciones!! gracias!!!